# Override a dependency of a dependency

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have a project A, which is compiled in Java 6. This depends on a project B, which is also compiled in Java 6.

Next to these, I have two projects, C-6 and C-7. C-6 is project C compiled in Java 6, while C-7 is compiled in Java 7.

Project B has a dependency to project C. By default, project B references to project C-7, meaning it uses the Java 7 version of project C. There are a lot of different projects referencing  to project B and they are all compiled in Java 7, so there is no problem here.

But now I have my project A, which is compiled in Java 6. Now I'd like to override the dependency of my dependency B. The problem is that even when I exclude C-7 in project A and add a dependency to C-6, the moment I call a method in project B, it'll get the class from C-7. Therefore, my application crashes since it's not compatible.

How can I solve this? How can I tell my dependency B to use a different dependency C than it usually depends on? Please keep in mind that a lot of projects use project B as dependency, so I prefer not changing anything that involves having to change other projects.

Answer (score 0):

Within a given dependency you can use the `exclusions` tag to exclude specified dependencies. If you then add a compatible dependency to your project then this library will be on your classpath rather than the excluded dependency. We use this feature all the time to swap out logging libraries. However, the technique is of limited value, as the library you put in must implement the same interface as they library you take out. Like I said, this works well for logging, but not very well for most other things.

It would look something like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.my.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>B</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>C7</exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.my.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>C6</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I understand that. However, if you use the exclude and include tag on project B to include/exclude C-6, project A has access to C-6 features, but when you call a method on project B, it'll call the C-7 method. I've explained this in my post, too.

Comment: Can you explain that a little more as I'm a little confused. As I understand it: you have A -> B -> C7, and you want A -> B -> C6. So, if you do A -> C6 & A -> B x-> C7, then this should exclude C7 from the classpath and put C6 on the classpath. (-> is a dependency and x-> is an exclusion). So, the exclusion goes on B's dependency in A, rather than on A, which is what I think your question states.

Comment: Not quite. You are correct in stating what I want. But the problem is, I can't exclude anything in B. Unless I can do something with (default) profiles or something like that. The point is, I'm working on project A. There are also teams working on W, X, Y, Z, .., all being the same in terms of dependency hierarchy (also clients) as project A. So I can't just exclude in project B, because that'll break all the other applications.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that you may be misunderstanding maven's dependency mechanism. You place the exclusion in A's pom, at the point where you depend on B. I have included a sample in my answer, above.